# nginx with .net core kestrel - multiple vs single instance

Tags: docker, nginx, .net-core, microservices

I have 4 .net core web applications running (3 'micro' services and one web site). I'm trying to decide on a deployment strategy using docker. As I understand, my options are as follows:

1. Total 4 containers - each container with a core app and a nginx instance
2. Total 8 containers - 4 .net core containers and 4 nginx containers
3. Total 5 Containers - 4 .net core containers and shared nginx container

Some Notes:

1. More services will also be added as time goes by.
2. This setup will be running on a linux
3. In the future, when the site load gets high I will want to do load balancing and to run each of the four websites on their own (multiple) servers. I would also want to fire up multiple instances of each service as they are stateless.

**Question is**; Is there a good reason to use separate nginx instances or should all .net apps use the same nginx container?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are valid, but probably the single nginx instance scenario is more flexible because in that case you can use the nginx as a gateway for your services, for things like SSL termination, authentication and so on. And by the way, if you are using ASP.NET Core 2.0, you can try to expose you services without nginx, because Kestrel is considered edge-ready in 2.0

Comment: I'm looking for using nginx to offload static files and for load balancing. I want to separate concerns here. Can you point to any documentation giving the 'go ahead' for direct kestrel?

Comment: The reverse proxy is still deemed necessary for Kestrel in dotnet-core 2.0 for a public facing app: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/

Comment: Where does it say that the reverse proxy is necessary? As I said, Kestrel is edge-ready in 2.0, it is an officially supported, though a bit risky, scenario. As for documentation, it is basically what you can find on the internet, not much.

Comment: See this video for details about Kestrel in the front facing scenario https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBUumVyafHw